# Group Concat Query Problem

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I know this may be impossible to answer, but I'm trying to figure out why a query is returning 0 results.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  records.instance_id
  ,instances.patient_id
  ,form_1_data.field_1 AS field_0
  ,form_1_data.field_2 AS field_1
  ,records.field_240 AS field_2
  ,**GROUP_CONCAT(events.start_time SEPARATOR '<br />')**  AS field_3 
FROM form_4_data AS records 
LEFT JOIN instances ON instances.id= records.instance_id 
LEFT JOIN events ON records.instance_id = events.instance_id  
LEFT JOIN form_3_data ON records.field_111= form_3_data.instance_id  
LEFT JOIN form_1_data ON form_3_data.field_94= form_1_data.instance_id 
WHERE instances.active=1  
ORDER BY records.instance_id DESC  
LIMIT 25,25
```

returns 0 results.

But,

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  records.instance_id
  ,instances.patient_id
  ,form_1_data.field_1 AS field_0
  ,form_1_data.field_2 AS field_1
  ,records.field_240 AS field_2
  ,**events.start_time AS field_3** 
FROM form_4_data AS records 
LEFT JOIN instances  ON instances.id= records.instance_id 
LEFT JOIN events ON records.instance_id = events.instance_id  
LEFT JOIN form_3_data ON records.field_111= form_3_data.instance_id  
LEFT JOIN form_1_data ON form_3_data.field_94= form_1_data.instance_id 
WHERE instances.active = 1  
ORDER BY records.instance_id DESC  
LIMIT 25,25
```

returns:

```
instance_id patient_id  field_0  field_1  field_2   field_3
83          40          Jack     Nichols  NULL      2011-04-11 20:00:00
60          8           Olive    Miller   Split     NULL
58          32          Mark     Green    NPSG      2011-03-05 20:00:00
58          32          Mark     Green    NPSG      2011-04-09 20:00:00
58          32          Mark     Green    NPSG      2011-04-02 20:00:00
58          32          Mark     Green    NPSG      2011-04-09 20:00:00
57          32          Mark     Green    MSLT      NULL
56          43          Jeremy   Stevens  NPSG      NULL
31          32          Mark     Green    MWT       2011-04-14 20:00:00
28          29          Jerry    Jones    NULL      2011-04-01 20:00:00
28          29          Jerry    Jones    NULL      2011-04-02 20:00:00
28          29          Jerry    Jones    NULL      2011-03-30 20:00:00
28          29          Jerry    Jones    NULL      2011-04-01 20:00:00
28          29          Jerry    Jones    NULL      2011-04-14 20:00:00
11           8          Olive    Miller   Split     2011-03-11 20:00:00
11           8          Olive    Miller   Split     2011-03-30 20:00:00
11           8          Olive    Miller   Split     2011-03-22 20:00:00
11           8          Olive    Miller   Split     2011-04-06 20:00:00
11           8          Olive    Miller   Split     2011-04-16 20:00:00
11           8          Olive    Miller   Split     2011-03-31 20:00:00
11           8          Olive    Miller   Split     2011-04-02 20:00:00
11           8          Olive    Miller   Split     2011-04-03 20:00:00
9            8          Olive    Miller   NPSG      2011-04-22 20:00:00
9            8          Olive    Miller   NPSG      2011-03-29 20:00:00
9            8          Olive    Miller   NPSG      2011-03-29 20:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_concat` does not work because there is no `group by` clause in your query.
Add a `group by` and it will work.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
  records.instance_id
  ,instances.patient_id
  ,form_1_data.field_1 AS field_0
  ,form_1_data.field_2 AS field_1
  ,records.field_240 AS field_2
GROUP_CONCAT(events.start_time SEPARATOR '<br />')  AS field_3
FROM form_4_data AS records 
LEFT JOIN instances ON instances.id= records.instance_id 
LEFT JOIN events ON records.instance_id = events.instance_id  
LEFT JOIN form_3_data ON records.field_111= form_3_data.instance_id  
LEFT JOIN form_1_data ON form_3_data.field_94= form_1_data.instance_id 
WHERE instances.active=1  
GROUP BY records.instance_id /*<<-- addition */
ORDER BY records.instance_id DESC  
LIMIT 25,25
```

Comment: Doh!  Thank you. I shouldn't try to write queries after 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just add a new line to your date then GROUP_CONCAT is not what you really need. It is an aggregate function working together with GROUP BY to concatenate strings from different rows in a groupped block.

If we have a table weeks:

```
week weekday
1    Monday
1    Tuesday
1    Friday
2    Monday
2    Sunday
```

a query

```
SELECT week, GROUP_CONCAT( weekday SEPARATOR '<br />' ) as days
FROM weeks
GROUP BY week
```

will give you:

```
week days
1    Monday<br />Tuesday<br />Friday
2    Monday<br />Sunday
```

I believe what you are looking for is a simple CONCAT:

```
SELECT week, CONCAT( weekday,'<br />' ) as day
FROM weeks
```

will give you:

```
week day
1    Monday<br />
1    Tuesday<br />
1    Friday<br />
2    Monday<br />
2    Sunday<br />
```